# Probability: Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

> Suppose  that two  teams play  a  series  of  games  that  ends  when  one  of  them  has  won  2 games. Suppose that each game played is, independently, won by team A with probability $p$. Let $N$ be the total number of games played. Find $\mathbb{E}[N]$ and $\mathbb{Var}(N)$.

Can someone please tell me if I'm on the right track? Feel free to destroy me.

[image: How I answered it]

Answer (score 1):

There can be either just two or three games total (of course).  (No ties allowed, I presume, otherwise you would have had to give us the probability of a tie.  Moreover, you imply just the two teams, otherwise you would have had to give us the probability for the other team winning.)

The terminal sequences are:  $AA, BB, ABA, ABB, BAB, BAA$.  Calculate the probability of each sequence and multiply by its length and add up:

${\cal E}[n] = p^2 \cdot 2 + (1-p)^2 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot p^2 (1-p) \cdot 2 + 2 (1-p)^2 p \cdot 2$

Can you calculate the variance, ${\cal V}[n]$?  There are just six terms (of course).

Comment: Hi David, I really appreciate the guidance, thanks! In the photo above I calculated variance to be -4p^4+8p^3-6p^2+2p.

Comment: do you think it's correct? @david-g-stork